# How to partially set arguments to a function without running it?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to make life as easy as possible for my users while providing them with complete flexibility. I need to write functions for them to use, but the trick is that a user needs to pick the function before running it. Here's what I would like to do:

```
def standardGenerator(obj,param=8.0):
   # algorithm which generates stuff based on obj and param
   return stuff

opts.usersChoice = standardGenerator
```

in this example, `opts` is an option container which is provided to the user to set whatever options they want. When they're done setting all their options, they pass `opts` back to me.

now the issue is that `obj` will not be known until after `opts` is in my hands, but maybe a user wants `params=4.0` instead of my default. My question is what is the easiest way to allow a user to set `param`?

here are the ideas I thought of:

```
def standardGenerator4(obj):
   return standardGenerator(obj,param=4.0)
opts.usersChoice = standardGenerator4

opts.usersChoice = lambda obj: standardGenerator(obj,4.0)
```

probably lambda is the best idea, but i'm wondering if there's some other way to do this without requiring users to know what a lambda function is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, another way to do this is to use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: I didn't know this existed. This is why we ask questions. The downside  here is that it requires a user to understand how `partial` works, which is even more obscure than `lambda`, and which requires an `import`. But if I put a few examples in the manual maybe they won't complain too much...

Comment: @amos, Well, by obscure I guess you mean "not widely known," in which case you are correct. But I suspect that for people who know nothing about `lambda` or `partial`, `partial` might be easier to explain. And depending on how your users are importing _your_ package, it shouldn't be too hard to get `partial` in there as well. One question worth considering -- perhaps you should just have another field in `opts` -- `usersChoiceParam`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not make it a class with `__call__`?

```
class standardGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, param=8.0):
        self.param = param
    def __call__(self, obj):
        # do stuff with obj and self.param
```

The users code does this:

```
opts.usersChoice = standardGenerator() # for default, or...
opts.usersChoice = standardGenerator(4.0)
```

Then `opts.usersChoice` is callable just like before, with only one argument for `obj`.

EDIT: If you have several functions and don't want to convert them all to classes, you could make a wrapper class:

```
class wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, func, **args):
        self.func, self.args = func, args
    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.func(*args, **self.kwargs)
```

Then your old function could be used "raw" the same as before, or like this for a user-defined argument:

```
opts.usersChoice = wrapper(standardGenerator, param=4.0)
```

I think the first solution is cleaner, and the second solution is probably starting to duplicate `functools.partial`, but you get the idea.

EDIT: Another thing you could do, which is arguably evil, is use operator overloading:

```
class _standardGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, param = 8.0):
        self.param = param
    # overload << to make it look most evil
    def __lshift__(self, other):
        return _standardGenerator(other)
    def __call__(self, obj):
        # do stuff with self.param and obj

standardGenerator = _standardGenerator()

# user code for default
opts.usersChoice = standardGenerator
# user code for nondefault
opts.usersChoice = standardGenerator << 4.0
```

Of course, I think it's infinitely cleaner to use a regular class and have the user instantiate it him/herself, but if you *really* don't like those parentheses on the end of `standardGenerator` something like this would do the trick.

Comment: +1, a callable class is a neat approach, though does add a bit of complexity.

Comment: I already anticipate that some of my more advanced users may want to make their own class and do it the way you've suggested. What I'm looking for here is the easiest way to write a few canned routines and provide a little bit of flexibility.

Comment: @amos - You could do some evil things with operator overloading, but otherwise I think the class (or the lambda) is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what I think you are, then your answer comes from argument unpacking.

```
opts.usersChoice = standardGenerator4
opts.usersArguments = (obj, 4.0)

opts.usersChoice(*opts.usersArguments)
```

This will call `standardGenerator4(obj,4.0)`.

You can use this with lists too, so you could build it up if needed:

```
opts.usersChoice = standardGenerator4
opts.usersArguments = [obj]
...
opts.usersArguments.append(4.0)
...
opts.usersChoice(*opts.usersArguments)
```

Would have the same result.

Comment: I think the problem is that the user doesn't have access to `obj` and so can't pass it as part of `usersArguments`.

Comment: My `opts` object is quite extensive, and I do something similar to this in other cases. I don't like the disconnect between the arguments and the function, if it can be avoided.